# Caml Query for "Contain ALL Of" or "Contains Any Of"

Tags: sharepoint, caml

So as an example let’s take the Title field and assume i want to set up a web part to display documents related to the search term ***American Civil War***.

The `contains all of` option would let me display documents that had all 3 words in the title i.e. the implied condition would be `American AND Civil AND War`
The `contains any of` option would give me any document where any of those words appear i.e. `American OR Civil OR War`

Both of these would be irrespective of the order of the words or any additional words that appeared

I need to create caml query in sharepoint 2010? Is there a direct way or better way to handle this above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will have to create multiple `AND` clauses with `CONTAINS` operator to achieve the desired *contains ALL of* behaviour. The same applies to multiple `OR` clauses with `CONTAINS` operator needed to archieve the *contains ANY of* behaviour.

Comment: Yes i have done in the same way, you have suggested, but OR clauses seems to give wrong results some times..

Comment: @user1899731 What do you mean by wrong results? I have never experienced the OR clause to misbehave.